# how to mask basin using ferret or cdo

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate

I have world map GRACE-data in netcdf file. I'm looking for visualizing data in a selected region, for instance just visualize the data for Amazon or Volga basin. I was suggested to use basin mask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following if you have a shapefile of your basin.

```
# convert shp to nc
gdal_rasterize -of netCDF -burn 1 -tr 0.01 0.01 basin.shp basin.nc

# regrid
cdo remapbil,infile.nc basin.nc basin2.nc

# mask
cdo ifthen basin2.nc infile.nc masked_infile.nc
```

Comment: super cool answer, I'll definitely make a note of this.

Comment: @Dani56 nice answer.  I want to rasterize (burn) each sub-shapefile in one shapefile with a unique value for each sub-shapefile. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to exactly follow a basin's boundaries and are happy to simply view a "rectangle" lat-lon region, then you can also simply do

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 world_file.nc region.nc
```